# How to grab a specific button tag inside of a class

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

I would like to add a class "hidden" to a 3rd button element inside of 2nd "moves" class. Is there something wrong in my code? Thanks.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("moves")[1].getElementsByTagName("button")[4].classList.add("hidden");
```

The html is below;
p.s. I just changed the index for this question to simplify my question. So dont mind about the index.

```
       <div class="moves">
          <button>
            <span class="move">Move Name Here</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
          <button>
            <span class="move">Move Name Here</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
          <button>
            <span class="move">Move Name Here</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
          <button>
            <span class="move">Move Name Here</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you share the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**
See according to your UI provided, there is only on 'move' class and only four button. so index position will get updated in your javascript code.
like in getElementsByClassName, index position will start from 0 i.e getElementsByClassName[0]. Similarly at getElementByTagName index position will start from 0 . so you will have to update index at '3', '3' is refering to your last button.

According to my previous answer, there were 5 buttons so i've used index position 4.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("moves")[0].getElementsByTagName("button")[3].classList.add("hidden");
```

```html
<div class="moves">
          <button>
            <span class="move">Move Name Here</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
          <button>
            <span class="move">Move Name Here</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
          <button>
            <span class="move">Move Name Here</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
          <button>
            <span class="move">Move Name Here</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
        </div>
```

see the below code snippe, i think that the scenario. You code us working fine, class is getting added to element. Inspect that element, you'll see it

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("moves")[1].getElementsByTagName("button")[3].classList.add("hidden");
```

```html
<div class="moves">
first
</div>
<div class="moves">
second
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
<button>4</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your version works because you have 5 buttons. The OP only has 4.

Comment: Thanx. since he didn't provided any html in first place, so i've created one of my own to show.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I changed the index, but there is still an error, which says 'Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined'...

Answer (score 0):

The **4th** button is actually index number *3*. Change *4* to **3** and you're done.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("moves")[1].getElementsByTagName("button")[3].classList.add("hidden");
```

You say that we shouldn't worry about the index, but the index you're providing will throw an error with your `HTML`. There is no 5th button.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I changed the index, but there is still an error, which says 'Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined'...

Comment: @AndyAnderson - how many `moves` divs are there? the error is clear, the 2nd `moves` does not contain 4 buttons. so maybe it's the 1st index that needs to be corrected.